# Is it possible to change Unbound Expression at run time?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

In my gridview, I created Unbound Column & Unbound Expression. Runtime in certain condition i need to change Unbound Expression, I perform another calculation and set the new calculated value to Unbounded Column. Is it possible to do ? Is it store new value or else it automatically store normal Unbounded Expression that i set on Property ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to change it. There is a section in the [online documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477)

> At runtime, an end-user can edit an unbound column's expression via an
>   Expression Editor. It can be opened via a context menu (if the
>   GridColumn.ShowUnboundExpressionMenu option is enabled) or in code via
>   the ColumnView.ShowUnboundExpressionEditor method.

You can also do this via code. You just need to set the `UnboundExpression` property of the unbound column.

```
columnExtPrice.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal;
columnExtPrice.UnboundExpression = "[Quantity] * [UnitPrice] * (1 - [Discount])";
```

As with all things DevExpress,
 the best place to ask is their [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Comment: Hi shamp00, My task is i already set unbound expression to a particular column[Field Name]. In some condition like Discount == "Discount" i need to recalculate that is expression must change to particular cell vaue in a row ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but it sounds like you should be including your condition in the `UnboundExpression`. For more control, you can use the `CustomUnboundColumnDataEvent` as demonstrated [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3008).